# How to exclude product categories from a function in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to exclude a specific product category using different ways, see in following code:

```
function isa_before_add_to_cart_form() {
    global $post;

    $demoslug = $post->post_name;

    $demourl = get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$demoslug.'-gratuito/';

    $demotitle = esc_attr($post->post_title);

    echo '<a href="'.$demourl.'" title="'.$demotitle.'" id="livedemo" class="button" target="_blank">testar</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','isa_before_add_to_cart_form');
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form','isa_before_add_to_cart_form');
```

But none of the ones I've tried works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to exclude a product category using `has_term()` function this way *(where `clothing` is the product category to be excluded)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'displayed_product_custom_button');
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'displayed_product_custom_button');

function displayed_product_custom_button() {
    global $post, product;

    if( ! has_term( array('clothing'), 'product_cat' ) ) {

        $demoslug = $post->post_name;

        $demourl = get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$demoslug.'-gratuito/';

        $demotitle = esc_attr($post->post_title);

        echo '<a href="'.$demourl.'" title="'.$demotitle.'" id="livedemo" class="button" target="_blank">testar</a>';
    }
}
```